# Filter the record not same from what I have within the same result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a result set, lets just assume that I joined multiple tables to pull the following result set.

And this is what I got

| ID | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12300 | $80 | $70 |
| 12300 | $70 | $80 |
| 12300 | $70 | $80 |
| 12313 | $10 | $100 |
| 12313 | $50 | $70 |
| 12510 | $50 | $70 |
| 12510 | $70 | $50 |
| 12510 | $10 | $120 |

I hope this make sense, how can I take away those record which column 2 has duplicate value in column 3?

For example, for ID 12300, $80 can be found in column 3 within the same ID, so does $70.

But 12313 has 2 different value so I need to keep those both.

12510 $50 and $70 can be found in column 3 but $10 is not, so i only need the last record.

That being said,  I wish my result look like this

| ID | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12313 | $10 | $100 |
| 12313 | $50 | $70 |
| 12510 | $10 | $120 |

I wish I can bring up my query, but its way too much.

So if anyway could give me some solutions to solve this will be much appreciated!

My guess will be using NOT EXISTS.

Thank you so much!

Comment: need the individual tables and some example data to be able to help with this one

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: "I wish I can bring up my query, but its way too much." - thats why you need to produce a [mre] with the emphasis on minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a left self join.  Like this:

```
declare @demo table (id int, col2 int, col3 int);
INSERT INTO @demo VALUES
(12300  ,80 ,70),
(12300  ,70 ,80),
(12300  ,70 ,80),
(12313  ,10 ,100),
(12313  ,50 ,70),
(12510  ,50 ,70),
(12510  ,70 ,50),
(12510  ,10 ,120);

SELECT c2.* 
FROM @demo c2
LEFT JOIN @demo c3 ON c2.col2 = c3.col3 AND c2.id = c3.id
WHERE c3.col2 IS NULL;
```

The self join links col2 and col3 for the same id, and then only those records are returned where the left join fails (IS NULL).

BTW for future questions, it is always helpful, if you provide SQL to create a table and insert data (as I have done in my answer).  People are much more willing to help, if they do not need to do so much typing themselves!

EDIT

If you want to use a NOT EXISTS then you construct it like this:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM @demo d
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM @demo
     WHERE col3 = d.col2
     AND id = d.id);
```

Comment: I appreciated for the solution. The reason that I did not share my query is because its combine with CTE/Temp Table and joined a lot of tables. But I will make it more clear and provide the table and insert some dummy data next time. Haven't try the solution yet, but is there anyway I can use NOT EXISTS or something else? As i mentioned, the query is contains multiple tables which hard to do a self join(unless i store the whole result set into a temp table and join itself)

Comment: Just saw ur updated comment. Thanks Jonathan

Comment: Even using NOT EXISTS as I have shown in my edit is self referential on the resultset.  It may be possible to circumvent this, but without seeing your full query, it is impossible to say.